# How to insert multiple rows of a invoice in a mysql db using flask

Tags: javascript, python, loops, flask

My html code is

```
<tr class="item-row">
  <td class="item-name">
    <div class="delete-wpr"><textarea name="item">Web Updates</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div>
  </td>

  <td class="description"><textarea name="description">Monthly web updates </textarea></td>
  <td><textarea class="cost" name="unitcost" required>0.0</textarea></td>
  <td><textarea class="qty" name="qty" required>1</textarea></td>
  <td><span class="price" name="pric">Rs 0.0 </span></td>
</tr>

<tr class="item-row">
  <td class="item-name">
    <div class="delete-wpr"><textarea>SSL Renewals</textarea><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div>
  </td>

  <td class="description"><textarea>renewals of SSL certificates </textarea></td>
  <td><textarea class="cost" required> 0.0</textarea></td>
  <td><textarea class="qty" required>1</textarea></td>
  <td><span class="price">Rs 0.0</span></td>
</tr>

<tr id="hiderow">
  <td colspan="5"><a id="addrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a></td>
</tr>
```

My python code is running only for inserting single row,i am newbie to this .Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How did you attempt to insert database rows in in python?

Comment: I have made a function for this with post request and have run a query for this.
 if request.method == 'POST'
  item = userDetails['item']
  description = userDetails['description']
   cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
   cur.execute("INSERT INTO invoiced(name,ad,gst,pan,train,num,dated,item,description,total,subtotal,words,email,newgst) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(name,ad,gst,pan,train,num,dated,item,description,total,subtotal,words,email,newgst))
   mysql.connection.commit()